# Dynamically Adjusting object values in a template?

Tags: angular

I am outputting the contents of an object array to a table in my template that has various movement rates.  A user can select a button that converts between various units of distance and would like to dynamically adjust the object value in the template based on the selected statement but for the life of me can't figure out how to do this without reloading the entire array everytime.

Is there a way to pass the object value to a helper method that recalculates it based on the units selected?  I was thinking I could build a helper method to recaculated the lists but I'm fairly new to Angular and this doesn't seem to be the way.  Thanks for any help.

```
this.movementRatesFlat =[  
  {
    terrain: 'Flat',
    path: 'Paved Road',
    foot: 5,
    horse: 10,
    cart: 5,
    wagon: 5
  },
  {
    terrain: 'Flat',
    path: 'Unpaved Road',
    foot: 5,
    horse: 9,
    cart: 5,
    wagon: 4
  }, ...
  ]
```

In the template I'm outputting the table like so:

```
  <tr *ngFor="let mr of movementRatesFlat">
    <td>{{mr.path}}</td>
    <td class="text-center">{{mr.foot}}</td>
    <td class="text-center">{{mr.horse}}</td>
    <td class="text-center">{{mr.cart}}</td>
    <td class="text-center">{{mr.wagon}}</td>
  </tr>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call a function from the template.
So, you could have:

```
 <tr *ngFor="let mr of movementRatesFlat">
    <td>{{mr.path}}</td>
    <td class="text-center">{{convert(mr.foot)}}</td>
    <td class="text-center">{{convert(mr.horse)}}</td>
    <td class="text-center">{{convert(mr.cart)}}</td>
    <td class="text-center">{{convert(mr.wagon)}}</td>
  </tr>
```

and in your component, you'd have something like:

```
public selectedUnits;

public convert(value) {
 return .... /* some function involving 'this.selectedUnits' */
}
```

Comment: Many thanks.  This got me where I needed to be.  I obscured the answer from myself because I had put the radio buttons for that set the this.selectedUnits property under a bootstrap trick to make them look like buttons.  I had to shift the click event to the label (that's actually clicked) instead of the radio button.